# IBM Websphere MQ authentication error while accessing channel

Tags: jms, ibm-mq

I am using IBM **Websphere MQ 7.5 in Unix system**. I have installed the client on my machine and server is running on other machine. I am observing a scenario where I am able to communicate with server when running my **JMS application via 'mqm' user** but facing below mentioned error when using other user.

But I am able to run 'amqsputc' and 'amqsgetc'  command and communicate with the server with mqm as well as other user also. I have followed all steps mentioned http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.ins.doc/q009300_.htm?lang=en

**Exception:**

```
com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSSecurityException: JMSWMQ2013: The security authentication was not valid that was supplied for QueueManager 'TestManager' with connection mode 'Client' and host name 'x.x.x.x(9923)'.
Please check if the supplied username and password are correct on the QueueManager to which you are connecting.
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.reasonToException(Reason.java:521)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:221)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConnection.<init>(WMQConnection.java:426)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createV7ProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:6902)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:6277)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.admin.JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.createConnection(JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.java:285)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory.createCommonConnection(MQConnectionFactory.java:6233)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection(MQQueueConnectionFactory.java:120)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory.createConnection(MQQueueConnectionFactory.java:203)
    at performance.IBMMQTestProducer.start(IBMMQTestProducer.java:142)
    at performance.IBMMQTestProducer.main(IBMMQTestProducer.java:177)   

Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2035' ('MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED').**
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:209)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2035;AMQ9509: Program cannot open queue manager object. [1=2035,5=???]**
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.internal.JmqiTools.getQueueManagerInfo(JmqiTools.java:783)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteSession.loadInfo(RemoteSession.java:1993)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteSession.getName(RemoteSession.java:2026)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteHconn.getName(RemoteHconn.java:728)
    at com.ibm.mq.ese.intercept.JmqiConnInterceptorImpl.validate(JmqiConnInterceptorImpl.java:321)
    at com.ibm.mq.ese.intercept.JmqiConnInterceptorImpl.afterConnect(JmqiConnInterceptorImpl.java:226)
    at com.ibm.mq.ese.intercept.JmqiConnInterceptorImpl.afterJmqiConnect(JmqiConnInterceptorImpl.java:133)
    at com.ibm.mq.ese.jmqi.InterceptedJmqiImpl.jmqiConnect(InterceptedJmqiImpl.java:315)
    at com.ibm.mq.ese.jmqi.ESEJMQI.jmqiConnect(ESEJMQI.java:337)
```

I am able to run it when I am running as myself and passing 'mqm' when starting the connection.

```
connection = cf.createConnection("mqm", "pswd");
```

I am not getting anything in manager's log. Below is the log.

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
10/30/2015 06:50:54 AM - Process(31064.1) User(mqm) Program(strmqm)
                    Host(x.x.x.x) Installation(Installation1)
                    VRMF(7.5.0.2)
AMQ7125: There are 83 days left in the trial period for this copy of WebSphere
MQ.

EXPLANATION:
This copy of WebSphere MQ is licensed for a limited period only.
ACTION:
None.
```

Comment: Is the JMS application connecting to the queue manager using the same SVRCONN channel you used for amqsputc/amqsget? Do you have channel auth enabled and channel auth records defined? The AMQERR0x.log files in /var/mqm/qmgrs/TestManager/errors should give you a more specific reason for the error saying which user ID MQ thinks you are connected as.

Comment: I have not used System specific channel. I created a channel on server side and used the same on client side. (In JMS application and also in amqsget and amqsput). I actually disabled channel auth : CHLAUTH(DISABLED). Do I need to enable them ? I thought it will remove all authentication and allow anyone to connect.

Comment: Yes CHLAUTH(DISABLED) will turn channel auth off which suggests the 2035 isn't caused by a channel auth rule. Are you passing a username and password to the JMS createConnection(userName, password) method, or using the version of createConnection() that doesn't take parameters? It's not clear why running your JMS app as mqm works and running it as another user doesn't, but there are many things that affect the username an MQ JMS client passes. Have you read http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21636093 ?

Comment: Please update your question with the error shown in the queue manager AMQERR01.LOG. Then we will be able to see the exact problem that caused the 2035.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you have told us that you have successfully connected and run the `amqsgetc` and `amqsputc` client samples using the same server-connection channel as you are attempting to use for your JMS program that suggests that this is not a connection time problem, in other words the `MQCONN` to the queue manager has been successful and something following that is failing. We know that you can `MQPUT` and `MQGET` (since that is what the aforementioned samples do).

Something that JMS does that those simple samples do not do, is an `MQINQ` of the queue manager. The following part of your exception makes me wonder if that is what you are tripping over:-

```
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2035;
AMQ9509: Program cannot open queue manager object. [1=2035,5=???] at 
com.ibm.mq.jmqi.internal.JmqiTools.getQueueManagerInfo(JmqiTools.java:783) at
```

To be completely certain you must check the queue manager `AMQERR01.LOG` to see what is reported there. If it is missing authorization then it will tell you there.